# How to add remove input mask dinamically in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I use ngx-mask, I can't remove or add it dynamically from directive.
When I use event emitter and re-bind value it nothing change.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o6fvnv)

HTML:

```
<input matInput [mask]="myMask" [(ngModel)]="dateModel">

<button type="button" (click)="removeMask()">RemoveMask</button>
<button type="button" (click)="addMask()">AddMask</button>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  myMask = '(0000)';
  tempData: null;

  public dateModel;

  removeMask() {
    this.myMask = null;
    this.tempData = this.dateModel;
    this.dateModel = null

  }

  addMask() {
    this.dateModel = this.tempData;
    this.myMask = '(0000)'
  }
}
```